# Rails Custom Route Gets Confused on :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to setup a custom route. However whenever I hit the beverage_locations/new page, it tries to send 'new' in the url as the :location_id in the index path.

**route.rb**

```
  controller 'beverage_locations' do
     get 'beverage_locations/:location_id' => 'beverage_locations#index'
     get 'beverage_locations/new' => 'beverage_locations#new'
  end
```

**error**

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BeverageLocationsController#index

Couldn't find Location with id=new
```

any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action’s
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.

From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions

A demo:

```
# beverage_locations_controller.rb
class BeverageLocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :text => params[:location_id]
  end

  def new
    render :text => 'New method'
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
Forfun::Application.routes.draw do
  controller 'beverage_locations' do
     get 'beverage_locations/new'          => 'beverage_locations#new'
     get 'beverage_locations/:location_id' => 'beverage_locations#index'
  end
end
# http://localhost:3000/beverage_locations/1234   =>  1234
# http://localhost:3000/beverage_locations/new    =>  New method
```

Comment: I am now getting a routing error:

No route matches {:controller=>"beverage_locations", :format=>nil}

Answer (score 3):

You need to swap the order of the routes so that the `new` action has preference:

```
controller 'beverage_locations' do
   get 'beverage_locations/new' => 'beverage_locations#new'
   get 'beverage_locations/:location_id' => 'beverage_locations#index'
end
```